# SQL choose first of duplicate results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hello I have a query that returns computer names with their corresponding IP adress as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[IP Address],
                                  dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[Host Name]
FROM dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification
INNER JOIN dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP 
   ON dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification._ResourceGuid = dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP._ResourceGuid
```

This is returning results such as:

```
Computer:               IP: 

Frank's Computer        10.0.0.1
Frank's Computer        10.0.0.3
Nick's Computer         10.0.1.0
```

Is it possible to just return the first "Frank's Computer" row, and exclude the other one?

Thanks!

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is what you need?

Comment: On one criteria do you want to put Frank first? Is it alfabetic? Without some criterion like that, you can't guarantee that records of a db are retrieved in the same order.

Comment: Why on earth are you using `TOP (100) PERCENT`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand While I agree with you completely, the engine should just ignore it (doesn't it?)

Comment: @Matthew yes, but why clutter up the code with meaningless nonsense?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, but how depends on your DBMS of choice. The functionality you are looking for is `GROUP BY`, which puts similar results together in a same column, but obviously then it does need to know what to do with non-aggregated values, by putting them in an aggregate function like `max`, `min` or `avg`.

Your results would look fine like this:

```
SELECT min(dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[IP Address]) AS IP, dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[Host Name] AS Name
FROM dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification
INNER JOIN dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP 
   ON dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification._ResourceGuid = dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP._ResourceGuid
GROUP BY dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[Host Name]
```

However the choice of IP for this is rather arbitrary now (`min` will do an alphabetic sort). In SQL Server and Oracle you can define a user defined aggregate function to better select which to show, in MySQL you could use something like `group_concat` which would probably perfectly fit your needs.

Comment: No, you can't `GROUP BY Name` because this was an alias derived in the `SELECT` list, and SQL Server parses `GROUP BY` first. You need to repeat the expression or derive the alias in a CTE/derived table.

Comment: @AaronBertrand well spotted, fixed in post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should stipulate **which** "Frank's Computer" row you want to include.

The one with the "minimum" IP? The first one inserted? The last one?

You likely want to use a `GROUP BY` clause, but will need to decide what sort of aggregation to use for the ip column. `MIN()`, `MAX()` ?

If you just want the "first" one in the return, that's coincidental... do you want to couple your result to the order of data on the page?

Comment: What about poor Nick?  He only wants to exclude the other computer from Frank.

Comment: @Blam what about him? Grouping by the user will certainly include him.

Comment: I'm not going to copy @Niels excellent answer above, but we have basically said the same thing. He provided a query.

Comment: But your answer did not group.  You later edited to include group.

Comment: @Blam you're right, I deleted that answer, updated it once I understood the question, then undeleted it. You deleted your initial comment, but apparently did not undo your downvote. We seem to be caught in some edit/page refresh loop. To me, it appears that the downvote occurred *after* I undeleted the edited answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[IP Address], dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[Host Name]
FROM         dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification INNER JOIN  dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP ON                                              dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification._ResourceGuid = dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP._ResourceGuid
and dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[Host Name] in (select top 1 dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP from dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification 
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP T ON dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_Identification._ResourceGuid = T._ResourceGuid and T.[IP Address] = dbo.Inv_AeX_AC_TCPIP.[IP Address])
```

Comment: Who ever down voted me, should explain his action, because this code does exactly what Richard asked for

Comment: The results are already distinct.  This answer does not remove duplicate IP.

Comment: @Pavel this does **not** do what was requested. The results posted are *already* distinct... the OP wants to ignore the *different* IP address values